# CycleOps Mag Trainer skewer doesn't fit

Tags: trainer

Can I use my CycleOps Mag Trainer without the skewer?

The skewer that came with my trainer does not fit properly. Does anyone know if I can use it with a Shimano Nexus 3/8" cap nut?

Answer (score 1):

Many axle nuts for an internal gear hub will fit directly without modification. If yours does not, then there are options to fix that, similar to the set from Tacx below.

As with many issues with trainers, there is a solution available for this issue.

This is a set of accessories designed to fit most solid or thru axle bikes.  You would need to make sure that you get a set that correctly fits your bike.

[Details of the accessory kit here.](http://www.tacx.com/en/products/trainers/booster/accessories-booster)

[image: Tacx Trainer Accessories for Solid axles and Thru Axles]

Answer (score 0):

All the clamp needs to do is hold the bike securely. If it holds securely and doesn't wobble it will be fine. I use an Elite trainer and have never used the skewer that came with it as I haven't had a problem with the one I have on my trainer wheel.

Comment: It isn't so simple with a Nexus hub since the compression of the trainer might mess up shifting.

Comment: It won't affect the shifting.